# Static Symbol Weak or Strong

Tags: c++, c, linker, symbols

Is a static uninitialized symbol a weak symbol or a strong symbol?

Can a uninitialized static symbol be overridden by a strong symbol?

Module 1:

```
static int y;
```

Module 2:

```
double y = 10;
```

Comment: gcc has good prefixes to handle weak symbols.

Comment: C++ doesn't have "modules" - unless something changed in the last decade or so, neither does C.  Do you mean translation units - i.e. typically one .c or .cc/.cpp/.c++ file and the file it directly or indirectly `#includes`?

Comment: Yes I mean translation units when linking.

Answer (score 3):

No. Static symbol is local to the defining module - not global, and cannot be overridden by any other module.

Comment: 'static' in module 1 hides the local "y" from other modules. so I will not receive a linking error?
Please let me know as I can't find it online?

Comment: That is correct. I don't see why you couldn't find it online - there are _loads_ of references that tell you what `static` does.